# distance function for android

Tags: android, sqlite

I just wanted to develop location based app which is using GPS. So i just surfing on the internet and i found spherical law of cosines for calculating the latitude and longitude. But while i tried to copy this function, i was stuck with some errors. seem android doesn't support sqlite3_context. so how could i fix it out ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have copied C code, and are pasting it into Android, which of course uses Java. While I'm sure the code will be similar when translated to Java, you must translate. In particular structs like sqlite_context don't exist in Java. But I'm sure there's some Android class like "SQLiteContext" that has a similar API.

Comment: hey sean, any exmaples for that cause i am newbie at android. thanks

Comment: hello sean, i already checked your link. but there's just a few lines explanation for data storage. could you please give me more hints for that ?

Answer (score 1):

if you have two locations object you could use distanceTo

```
Location loc1, loc2;
int distanceMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
```

Comment: Hey Ste, my problem is that eclipse pointing * symbol as a error. how could i fix it ? thanks anyway for your fast reply.

Comment: Why you need to use sqlite? are the coordinates store in an sqlite db?
try to import android.database.sqlite

Answer (score 1):

As addition to Ste's Answers:

if your points are stored in Database, the only way to compute distance to read them all from DB, to create Location's objects and to compute distance.

P.s.
If you are only interested to get aproximated distance there are some workarounds:
[Get next N nearest Geo-Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382471/get-next-n-nearest-geo-points)